# I want an entry box to get the input from another entry box if left blank to be input into an SQL Server Database

Tags: python, sql-server, date, tkinter

I am building a registration form GUI in python using Tkinter. If I leave one entrybox empty, I want the value of another entrybox to be supplemented for the empty entrybox to be put in an SQL Server Database.
This is my code attempt:

```
 self.L7 = Label(self.section3, text = "Urlaub am/vom")
        self.L7.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5, side = LEFT)

        ## ---- dDateStart

        self.dDateStart = Entry(self.section3)
        self.dDateStart.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5, side = LEFT)

        ## ---- dDateStart

        self.L8 = Label(self.section3, text = "bis einschl.")
        self.L8.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5, side = LEFT)
        
        ## ---- dDateEnd
        
        self.dDateEnd = Entry(self.section3)
        self.dDateEnd.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5, side = LEFT)

        if self.dDateEnd == Entry(None):
            self.dDateEnd.get(self.dDateStart)
```

This is the code that sends the entries to the database:

```
def submit(self):
        sql = """INSERT INTO dbo.PC_RequestTable (nRequest,dDateStart, dDateEnd, nEmployee, sReason, sStatus)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""
        values = (1, self.dDateStart.get(), self.dDateEnd.get(), self.nEmployee.get(), self.T1.get("1.0", "end"), "anhängig")
 
        self.cursor.execute(sql, values)
        self.cnxn.commit()
```

Is it possible to accomplish what I want? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to do the checking inside `submit()` instead of just after the entry (`self.dDateEnd`) is created.

Comment: @acw1668 I move the conditional inside of submit but I am still not getting the desired value

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the checking and assignment inside `submit()`:

```
def submit(self):
    start_date = self.dDateStart.get().strip()
    end_date = self.dDateEnd.get().strip()
    if start_date:
        if end_date == '':
            # end date empty, copy from start date
            end_date = start_date

        sql = """INSERT INTO dbo.PC_RequestTable (nRequest, dDateStart, dDateEnd, nEmployee, sReason, sStatus)
                 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""
        values = (1, start_date, end_date, self.nEmployee.get(), self.T1.get("1.0", "end"), "anhängig")

        self.cursor.execute(sql, values)
        self.cnxn.commit()
    else:
        print('Should at least input start date!')
```